# how to stop base page from reloading when using jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following code on my editRecords.php page. This page is a table of records and when I cick the view link it opens a dialog box with the displayRecord.php page in it. The problem is if I open the last record in the table instead of the dialog box opening/closing and the editRecords.php page remaining as is, it appears to reload which takes me back to the top of the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

     //creating a dialog box
     var dlg=$('#ticketDetails').dialog({
        title: 'Ticket Details',
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen:false,
        modal: true,
        hide: 'fade',
        width: 1300

     });

    //loading dialog box with record
    $('a.view').click(

    function(e) 
    {
         dlg.load('displayRecord.php?id='+this.id, function(){ 
         dlg.dialog('open');
         });

      });

});
```

I have tried using `e.preventDefault()` but this causes the dialog box to load with focus in the middle instead of the top.

```
function(e) 
        {
                 //tested here e.preventDefault();
             dlg.load('displayRecord.php?id='+this.id, function(){ 
             dlg.dialog('open');
             });
         //tested here e.preventDefault();
```

How can fix/adjust this behaviour?

Thanks.

**CLARIFICATION:** 
`e.preventDefault()` works but the problem is it causes the dialog to load with the focus in the middle. I have no problem opening or closing the dialog. I just want to stop the base page(editRecords.php) from reloading (or what appears to be like a page reload) so that when I close the dialog I see the record I clicked instead of having to scroll down again.

Answer (score 0):

Let us see how to load content dynamically inside this Dialog

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Load Page Dynamically inside a jQuery UI Dialog</title>
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
" />
<script  type="text/javascript" src="
http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ()    {
        $('<div>').dialog({
            modal: true,
            open: function ()
            {
                $(this).load('Sample.htm');
            },         
            height: 400,
            width: 400,
            title: 'Dynamically Loaded Page'
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, we are creating a div element on the fly and specifying a callback for the open event, which loads the content of the page ‘Sample.htm’ dynamically.

Opening and closing the dialog multiple times will not remove the dialog from the page. If you want to implement the close event, use this code in the dialog options (untested code):

`close: function(e, i) { $(this).close(); }`

That’s all!

Comment: Thanks for that but perhaps my question wasn't clear. See update! : ]